# How to update a Java Instant

Tags: java, datetime

I want to update an Instant object so that I can compare with it again.

```
Instant mvTime = Instant.now();
// Some Code
// Some More Code
```

Below code is executed many times:

```
Instant currentTime = Instant.now();                            
Duration timeBetween = Duration.between(mvTime, currentTime);
if (timeBetween.getSeconds() > Long.parseLong("120")) {
    doSomething()
    mvTime = mvTime.plusSeconds(Long.parseLong("180"));
}
```

The problem is that I want to update the same instance. How can I do that?

Comment: You didn't state any problem. But I guess the issue lies in a fact, that plusSeconds returns new instance.

Comment: but why is that a problem?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj yes exactly. I want to update the same instance object

Comment: First, stop using a  `String` each time you want to get `120L` and `180L`. Now, you can't update the instance, your actual code is correct, create a new instance with the update. Now, they are different approch but what you have is not bad (except for the `Long.parseLong(String)`

Comment: @AxelH So there's no way to update the same instance?

Comment: Nope, "This class is immutable and thread-safe." [Instant javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and this is true for (I believe) every classes in `java.time`.

Comment: By the way, may I suggest you replace `Long.parseLong("120")` with `120`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html

> This class is immutable and thread-safe.

You cannot change the *instance*, every method that *would* mutate the instance instead returns an adjusted copy of itself.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to update `mvTime`, you can use several methods on your `mvTime`, such as:

- plusSeconds()
- plusMillis()
- plusNanos()
- minusSeconds()
- minusMillis()
- minusNanos()

note that calling this method, will return a new `Instant` object